# Sending F1 - F12 key with external keyboard with missing keys on an iPad Pro using SSH emulation software

Tags: keyboard, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, latex

I am using an iPad Pro with an external keyboard (Smart Keyboard) for connecting via SSH (via [Serverauditor](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=serverauditor&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)) to an Ubuntu remote server in which I have the tex distribution installed. I use VIM to edit the text and the plugin VIM-LaTeX requires some of the <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> keys.

The problem is that my physical keyboard does not have these keys.

Some possible work around.

1. In order to use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button with VIM I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, maybe there are some combinations of key that like this one that can help me.
2. A solution could be to remap the keys I need to something else but I don’t know how to do it since I am a beginner with Ubuntu. In this case I would like also to know from the ones that are experienced with vim and vim-latex, which keys would be a good choice.
3. Is Emacs a good alternative or those keys are still required?
4. My last option is to use some on screen buttons that Serverauditor offers to emulate the keys that are missing.

Comment: Regarding your workaround #1: I'm sure that is the case.  Probable details at [Function keys over terminal](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53589/97078)

Comment: Get yourself a real computer. Seriously.

Comment: I have a real computer in my room, I prefer a tablet when at university and not a generic tablet, I find iPad Pro AMAZING

Comment: To TOOGAM, I am not able to use what you linked me. The combinations are awkward to press and I am not able to use them (I press the keys all together or one by one but nothing happens). I am trying to remap some VIM keys to the combination but I can figure how to do it right.