# Remap any key to F5 in Vim

Tags: vim, remapping, function-keys, nnoremap

I am trying to remap a key (I do not matter which) to F5 key because my physical keyboard hasn't got F1 - F12 keys. How can I do it?

I have tried to use `nnoremap` but I am doing something wrong. I have tried `:nnoremap ; <F5>`

#### Edit 1:

I think `;` is an invalid key, I am now trying various things with `<Space>` but I am not able to obtain what I want.

Comment: You want to remap any key to F5 but you said your keyboard doesn't have F1-F12

Comment: I mean that I would like that pressing Space it act like pressing F5

Comment: What OS? - Windows, Mac, Linux?

Comment: I al using iOS to connect via SSH to an Ubuntu, where I launch Vim

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending F1 - F12 key with external keyboard with missing keys](http://superuser.com/questions/1013761/sending-f1-f12-key-with-external-keyboard-with-missing-keys)

Comment: What is F5 supposed to do in vim? Here F5 does nothing in vim.

Comment: It expands some snippets in vim-latex

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I strongly suspect that <kbd>F-5</kbd> is a mapped key, so you're using `nnoremap` to try to map a key to another mapped key.

The `:nore` versions of the various map commands tell Vim explicitly *not* to trigger a second mapped key sequence to the right-hand-side (rhs) of the mapping.

In other words, the solution is to use `:nmap` instead of `:nnoremap`, and it should then work.

See `:help :nore`